# Can i travis-ci using multiple language and multiple os?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, travis-ci

My travis job is deploy for react-native. so, i want to build and android and ios at the same time without expo(expo is so good service. but, i want to some native code for native libraries)

Fully logic

- language: node_js

  - `npm ci` for react-native libraries
- language: ruby

  - `gem install fastlane`
- language: android, os: linux

  - i don't know why osx image couldn't use oraclejdk8 (see bottom)
- language: object-c os: osx

  - i couldn't try... i fixing some codes...

someone help me?

```
os: osx
osx_image: xcode10.1

matrix:
  include:
    - language: node_js
      node_js:
        - node
        - lts/*
      cache: npm
    - language: ruby
      rvm:
        - 2.6
      cache: bundler

before_script:
  - npm install -g npm@latest
  - gem update --system
  - gem install fastlane -NV
  - fastlane update_fastlane
  - npm ci

jobs:
  include:
    - stage: Deploy Android Test
      if: branch = rework-travis and type = push
      language: android
      jdk: openjdk8
      before_cache:
        - rm -f $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
        - rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/*/plugin-resolution/
      cache:
        directories:
          - $HOME/.gradle/caches/
          - $HOME/.gradle/wrapper/
      android:
        components:
          - tools
          - platform-tools
          - android-28

          - extra-google-google_play_services
      before_script:
        - chmod +x ./android/gradlew
      script:
        - ./android/gradlew assembleRelease
```

```
$ ~/bin/install-jdk.sh --target "/Users/travis/openjdk8" --workspace "/Users/travis/.cache/install-jdk" --feature "8" --license "GPL"
install-jdk.sh 2019-03-22
Expected feature release number in range of 9 to 13, but got: 8
The command "~/bin/install-jdk.sh --target "/Users/travis/openjdk8" --workspace "/Users/travis/.cache/install-jdk" --feature "8" --license "GPL"" failed and exited with 3 during .
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would use two different environments for your build - [Trusty](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/trusty/) CI for the android app and [macOS](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/osx/) CI for the iOS app. In your config you have only one environment defined.

You can read how to set up two environments [here](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/7371).

With Trusty CI, you can use [openjdk8](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/trusty/#jvm-clojure-groovy-java-scala-images), as it comes as the default and preinstalled one.